# How to print whitespaces in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to implement a shell function to print a specific number of "space" characters, to provide padding for fixed-width console output.

```
#!/bin/bash

function printWhiteSpaces
{
  local i="122"
  local len="$1"
  local whitespace=' '
  local k=`expr $i - $len`
  while [ $k -gt 0 ]
  do
    echo "${whitespace}"
    ((k--))
  done
}
```

The above function takes in a single argument as a "length of something", then I take the difference of the desired field width (122) and the argument `$1`. And I wish to print ***that*** many whitespace characters.

Why won't the above print any whitespaces? If anyone has a solution or an improvement to the above function please share. In particular I want to know if there's a better way to write this function that prints concatenated whitespace characters.

**Solution so far**:

```
#!/bin/bash

function printWhiteSpaces
{
  local i="122"
  local len="$1"
  local k=`expr $i - $len`
  local whitespace=' '
  while [ $k -gt 0 ]
  do
    echo -n "${whitespace}"
    ((k--))
  done
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your aim is to simply print a string variable with a fixed, whitespace-padded field length, I would recommend using the `printf` function of `bash`:

```bash
printf "%122s" "$myvar"
```

will print the content of `$myvar` with as much space to the left as is necessary to fill 122 characters in total.

Try this simple test (field width taken as 20 for readability):

```
~> myVar="Hi, there!"; printf '%20s\n' "$myVar"
          Hi, there!
~> myVar="Bye!"; printf '%20s\n' "$myVar"
                Bye!
```

Your original approach didn't work because `echo` will implicitly print a newline at the end.

If you want to use a shell loop and only `echo`, you have to call it as `echo -n` to inhibit the newline:

```
~> myVar="Bye!"; l=${#myVar}; for ((i=20;i>l;i--)); do echo -n ' '; done; echo "$myVar"
                Bye!
```

Comment: @ChristopherTruong Note that `printf`requires a format string as its first argument.

Comment: While the printf seems like a better solution, if you're determined to use echo, you could make 'whitespace' a string of 122 spaces and do something like `echo "${whitespace:0:\`expr $i - $len\`}"`

Comment: @BrandonXavier Your suggestion gave me only a single character.

Comment: My mistake - replace the `\`expr $i - $len\`` with just `$k` (the expr won't see the unexported variables)

Comment: Like this:    echo -n "${whitespace:0:$k}" ?

I still get a single character.

Comment: @BrandonXavier, `$i` and `$len` are expanded on the command line of `expr` there, exporting doesn't come to it. Anyway, no need for `expr` since the shell can do arithmetic on it's own, and esp. inside `${var:n:m}` it's an arithmetic context already. So just write `echo "${whitespace:0: i - len}"`.

Answer (score 1):

This script (tested with bash and sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

function printWhiteSpaces() {
  local i="122"
  local len="$1"
  local k=`expr $i - $len`
  local whitespace='                                                                                                                                                                  '
  echo "${whitespace:0:$k}" test
}

printWhiteSpaces 100
printWhiteSpaces 110
printWhiteSpaces 120
```

Produced the following output, which I believe is what you wanted:

```
                       test
             test
   test
```

(This was done on a Mac - doubt that would make a difference though)

Comment: `sh` on a mac might be some feature-rich shell. `function foo()` is a ksh-ism, the POSIX declaration is just `foo() { ... }`. You could use `$(( i - len ))` instead of `expr` and  And `${whitespace:0:$k}` sadly isn't posix, so won't work on a feature-restricted sh like Dash.

Comment: Just tested on a CentOS 7.9 system - the script behaved correctly under both bash and sh, and with/without the `function` in the declaration (which, BTW, was copied from the OP script)

Comment: `sh` on CentOS might also be Bash. I don't doubt it works on Bash, I'm just pointing out that `foo()` works more widely, without a downside. Debian/Ubuntu has Dash as `/bin/sh` by default, and it's not once or twice that people have tripped on that when implicitly assuming all shells are Bash. See e.g. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh and https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/ . Busybox's sh is similar to Dash, and comes up often-ish on embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function we can tamper with the command line . So we freshly create a command line of $k number of arguments (all null). After the construction is done we echo the command line `$*` in double quotes will give IFS first char(= space ) separated arguments and since the arguments were all null, we will see only a sea of spaces.

```
function printWhitespaces
{
  local i="122"
  local len="$1"
  local whitespace=' '
  local k=`expr $i - $len`
  set -- ""
  while [ "$#" -le "$k" ]
  do
    set -- "$@" "$1"
  done
  echo "$*"
}
```

---

And another approach, if you already have computed the $k variable is:

```
printf '%*s\n' "$k" ""
```